# firestore сохранение данных локально

Tags: java, android, firebase

Мне нужно что бы приложение читало только новые данные, а остальные(ранее скачанные) хранило оффлайн и не скачивало заново.

Из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868580/firestore-using-cache-until-online-content-updates) поста я понял что для этого нужно использовать **SnapshotListener** вместо **get**. И да я проверил, get если есть подключение к сети качает данные с сервера, а  **SnapshotListener** берет оффлайн, но не всегда. Я не могу понять причин, но иногда данные берутся с сервера(на сервере данные не изменялись).

В некоторых активностях данные всегда берутся с сервера, а в некоторых при запуске приложения - данные берутся локально, но при перезапуске активности они уже берутся с сервера.

Также я попробовал поставить два абсолютно одинаковых запроса рядом, то есть если один загрузится онлайн, то второй должен по логике брать уже локально, но нет, оба берутся с сервера.

Код

```
   FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
   db.collection("collection")
  .whereEqualTo("language", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
       .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                            return;
                        }
    
                        if(value != null && !value.isEmpty()){
                          // some code.
                        }
    
                        String source = value.getMetadata().isFromCache()? "local cache" : "server";
                        Log.d("DATAFROM", source);//тут можно понять откуда данные.
                    }
                });
```

PS: без whereEqualTo тоже не работает.

Что интересно, если отключить интернет, то все данные есть оффлайн и нормально загружаются...

Зачем это исправлять- потому что оплата берется за чтение, и какой смысл читать и платить за уже прочитанные данные!!?

Как это исправить?

Comment: Интересует тот же вопрос, получилось разобраться?

Comment: нет, перепробовав  все, я так и не нашел причин. Единственное что еще приходит в голову, так это пометка "Бета", так что может стоить спросить разрабов на прямую и ожидать что однажды проблема пропадет сама собой после того как они пофиксят ее.  Потому что это не может быть нашей ошибкой, я только что открыл приложение проверить  - в итоге один и тот же запрос берет то локально то с сервера. В любом случае стоит поискать причины.